# Passing an Image in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i am currently doing an app where i will need to pass the details of a selected pet to a new "Profile" page. As it stands, i have gotten all the data i require to pass (name,age etc) to go to my new profile page but i now have the problem that as i try to pass the photo of the selected pet through it crashes the app.

Firstly this is where i have declared my generic list, in the app.xaml

```
 private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Johnny", Age= 2, Breed="Husky", Type= "Dog", Stock = 1, Price = 125, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Husky.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Billy", Age= 1, Breed="Shiba Inu", Type= "Dog", Stock = 1, Price = 250, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Shiba Inu.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Sammy", Age = 8, Breed="Siamese", Type="Cat", Stock = 1, Price = 15, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Siamese Cat.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Molly", Age = 6, Breed="Norwegian", Type="Cat", Stock = 1, Price = 30, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/NorwegianForestCat.jpeg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Nemo", Age = 3, Breed="Clown Fish", Type="Fish", Stock = 1, Price = 10, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/clown Fish.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Dory", Age = 1, Breed="Palette SurgeonFish", Type="Fish", Price = 75, Stock = 1, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Palette Surgeonfish.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Keith", Age = 4, Breed="Bearded Dragon", Type="Lizard", Stock = 1, Price = 750, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Bearded Dragon.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop {Name = "Oisin", Age = 12, Breed = "Gecko", Type = "Lizard", Stock = 1, Price = 90, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Gecko.jpg" });
    }
```

Here is where i am attempting to pass through the details

```
    private void list_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Shop selectedPet = list.SelectedItem as Shop;

        String photo = selectedPet.Photo;
        String breed = selectedPet.Breed;
        String name = selectedPet.Name;
        int age = selectedPet.Age;
        int price = selectedPet.Price;

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Profile.xaml?name=" + name + "&breed=" + breed + "&age=" + age + "&price=" + "€" + price + "&photo=" + photo, UriKind.Relative));  
    }
```

That part of the code was working just fine and was passing the details correctly but now that i have added in the photo to be passed it is crashing. This is the code where i call the passed data to the new page

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string photo;
        string name;
        string age;
        string breed;
        string price;

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("photo", out photo))
            {
                imgPhotoHolder.Source = null;

                BitmapImage myImage = new BitmapImage
                (new Uri("/Assignment 1;component/Images/" + photo, UriKind.Relative));

                imgPhotoHolder.Source = myImage;
            }
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name))
            {
                nameTxtBlock.Text = name;
            }
            if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("age", out age))
            {
                ageTxtBlock.Text = age;
            }
            if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("breed", out breed))
            {
                breedTxtBlock.Text = breed;
            }
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("price", out price))
            {
                priceTxtBlock.Text = price;
            }
     }
```

The problem seems to arise from this snippet of code

```
+ "&photo=" + photo
```

The reason i know this is because when you comment out just that bit of code it will work fine and pass the details but when uncommented it will cause the app to crash when you select an item of the shop (see pictures below)

So i was just wondering if anybody has an idea on how to fix this bit of code or how to correctly get the image to pass through to the next page.
Thanks in advance,
Jason

The point where you select an image:

[image]

When you have clicked an image and where the details should display:

[image]

Comment: The fact that when i try to pass an image into the profile page it just crashes the app

Comment: ...And it crashes the app with which exception? *What is the error?*

Comment: (Sorry for sounding like such a beginner, i am pretty  new) but there is no actual error coming up, so i tried to run it through the debugger and when i do this it just redirects me to the app.xaml page and this line of code  private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

private void btnDetails_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Animals selectedAnimals = lstAnimals.SelectedItem as Animals;

```
        if (!(lstAnimals.SelectedItem == null))
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Details.xaml?" + "name=" + selectedAnimals.Name + "&"
            + "breed=" + selectedAnimals.Breed + "&" + "gender=" + selectedAnimals.Gender + "&"
            + "DOB=" + selectedAnimals.DOB + "&" + "price=" + selectedAnimals.Price + "&"
            + "photo=" + selectedAnimals.Photo, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));   
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Pet Selected");
        }

    }
```

Bop bop bop

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string name, breed, photo, gender, DOB, price;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name))
            txtName.Text = name;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("breed", out breed))
            txtBreed.Text = breed;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("gender", out gender))
            txtGender.Text = gender;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("DOB", out DOB))
            txtDOB.Text = DOB;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("price", out price))
            txtPrice.Text = price;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("photo", out photo))
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/PetShop_A2;component/" + photo, UriKind.Relative));
            imgDetails.Source = image;
        }
    }
```

You're the designer

Answer (score 0):

Your photo string value is formatted like this

"/Assignment 1;component/Images/SomeImageName.jpg"

and you're sending that as a parameter.

On the second page, you take that value out and form an Uri like this:

```
new Uri("/Assignment 1;component/Images/" + photo...
```

which effectively creates an URI for this:

/Assignment 1;component/Images//Assignment 1;component/Images/SomeImageName.jpg

That looks wrong.
You should probably just create the Uri based on the Photo string

```
BitmapImage myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(photo, UriKind.Relative));
```

and make sure that the Build action for your photo files is set to Resource.

Comment: I have taken the steps you have advised but unfortunately the app is still crashing

Answer (score 0):

In this OnNavigatedTo method you need to set write path for your image like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    { 
        try
        {
        string photo;
        string name;
        string age;
        string breed;
        string price;

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("photo", out photo))
            {
                imgPhotoHolder.Source = null;

                BitmapImage myImage = new BitmapImage
                (new Uri(photo, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                imgPhotoHolder.Source = myImage;
            }
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name))
            {
                nameTxtBlock.Text = name;
            }
            if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("age", out age))
            {
                ageTxtBlock.Text = age;
            }
            if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("breed", out breed))
            {
                breedTxtBlock.Text = breed;
            }
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("price", out price))
            {
                priceTxtBlock.Text = price;
            }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
     }
```

Comment: I have taken the steps you have advised but unfortunately the app is still crashing

Comment: have you debug this OnNavigatedTo method and what you are getting in out photo parameter and also check for exception and find out exception type using try catch block in your code

Comment: Unfortunately this try catch didn't fix the crashing problem. I have ran the debugger with a breakpoint at the OnNavigatedTo method but it just redirects me to the NavigationFailed event in the app.xaml.

Comment: put your break point in Application_UnhandledException method in app.xaml.cs file.

Comment: and know about exception detail

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem comes from the way i have called the photo on the list_SelectionChanged_1 event. Where i have this piece of code >> &photo=" + photo+ ,commented out it works fine but when it is not commented it crashes

Comment: dear friend crash comes due to exception know the type of exception and google for that exception...

Comment: Ok, i have put the breakpoint there and this is what it is saying the dialogBox >> Navigation is only supported to relative URIs that are fragments, or begin with '/', or which contain ';component/'.
Parameter name: uri

Comment: use this UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute istead of UriKind.Relative

Comment: try Photo = "../Images/Husky.jpg" or Photo = "..Images/Husky.jpg" Path instead of "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Husky.jpg" when you are binding your list in Application_Launching event

Comment: as i show your message this error is coming due to your incorrect image path

Comment: http://mobileosgeek.com/navigation-is-only-supported-to-relative-uris-that-are-fragments-error-in-windows-phone-app/

Comment: use this link regarding your exception